# Modify Resource in Design Time, with code behind in WPF project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, resources, expression-blend

**What I'm trying to do right now:** Modify the Expression Blend UI / Visual Studio, to add a button on one of my dependency properties, and when I click on it, it creates a new trigger.

**What is working**: I created the button, it appears in the UI, that's fine.

**What is not working**: I cannot modify the Resource to add a trigger (if I step in, it works but it does not modify on the global resource, only on the instance I think).

I have my main project in Visual Studio, and a property with a button like this:

[image: Visual Studio UI]

When the button is pressed this is what happens:

- I get my Control that contains that dependency property (Ok).
- I searched for the Resource file that contains the Resource I want to modify (Ok).
- I update the Resource, but it does not replace the Resource on disk.

I think that it's because I only modify it on memory, so it's in the "air"

I don't know where to go now... I need help

The code behind where I modify the Resource is in an other DLL, the MyLibrary.**Design**.cs

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 / Blend 4 / .NET 4.0

Comment: OMG how did you do that? i need to do something like that for one of the properties of the VS 2010 EDMX designer

Comment: You can take a look at http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/DesignerExtensbility

Answer (score 0):

That's one splution I can figure at the moment, but unfortunately I'm not able to test it now. Still you can check if it works for you.

You can have a class, say `ResourceContainer.cs`, and collect your control in it as a public static value, and let your control be a button:

```
   public static Button MyButton;
```

Then you can use it in your code-behind:
If your window is `MainWindow.xaml`, and, say you need your particular control in a grid, then you probably have something like:

```
<Window x:Class=...
        ...(namespace stuff)...
        Title="MainWindow" ...(size stuff)...>

    <Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    ...(your code here)...      
    </Grid>
    ...
</Window>
```

Then in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` you can use `ResourceContainer.cs` like this:

```
...
ResourceContainer rc;

...

MyGrid.Resources.Add("MyKey", rc.MyButton);

...

(when you need it)
rc.MyButton.Triggers.Add(TriggerBase item);
...
```